# Cómo convertir filas especificas en observaciones de una nueva variable en R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

quisiera saber cómo puedo transformar las filas de una tabla en valores que estén en un nueva columna, a partir de una fila en especifico, por ejemplo, tengo esta tabla donde las secciones vienen en la columna "name" y en las demás filas vienen los nombres, entonces quiero quitar la las filas que dicen nombre de sección y dejarlas como variable para filtrar y demás.

````
   name       F1   F2  F3          
Sectionname_AB            
activity_a          
activity_b     1    2   
activity_c          3
activity_d     1    3   
activity_e          
activity_f          3
activity_g     3    
activity_h     3        
activity_i          
Sectionname_BC           
activity_j     2        
activity_k     1    
activity_l     1    3   
activity_m     3        2
activity_n     3        2
activity_o     2    
```

Mi objetivo sería construir en R una tabla como esta: 

  name        F1   F2  F3   section         
activity_a                  Sectionname_AB
activity_b     1    2       Sectionname_AB
activity_c          3       Sectionname_AB
activity_d     1    3       Sectionname_AB
activity_e                  Sectionname_AB
activity_f          3       Sectionname_AB
activity_g     3            Sectionname_AB
activity_h     3            Sectionname_AB
activity_i                  Sectionname_BC
activity_j     2            Sectionname_BC
activity_k     1            Sectionname_BC
activity_l     1    3       Sectionname_BC
activity_m     3        2   Sectionname_BC
activity_n     3        2   Sectionname_BC
activity_o     2            Sectionname_BC
````

Comment: El tema es como diferenciar unas filas de otras, por el ejemplo, ¿podríamos asumir  que las filas de sección tiene `NA` en las tres columnas  aparte del nombre? Sería bueno que compartas un ejemplo más fácil de trabajar, por ejemplo copiando la salida de `dput(head(tu_df, 20))`

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tus datos son así (en lo posible comparte tus datos):

```
data <- structure(list(name = c("Sectionname_AB", "activity_a", "activity_b", 
"activity_c", "activity_d", "activity_e", "activity_f", "activity_g", 
"activity_h", "activity_i", "Sectionname_BC", "activity_j", "activity_k", 
"activity_l", "activity_m", "activity_n", "activity_o"), F1 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L
), F2 = c(NA, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA), F3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Una forma sencilla, asumiendo que es posible identificar las líneas pertinentes porque contienen la palabra "Sectionname", es usar `fill` de `tidyr`:

```
data$Sectionname = ifelse(grepl("Sectionname",data$name), data$name, NA)
data <- tidyr::fill(data, Sectionname)
data <- data[!grepl("Sectionname",data$name), ]

#>          name F1 F2 F3    Sectionname
#> 2  activity_a NA NA NA Sectionname_AB
#> 3  activity_b  1  2 NA Sectionname_AB
#> 4  activity_c NA  3 NA Sectionname_AB
#> 5  activity_d  1 NA  3 Sectionname_AB
#> 6  activity_e NA NA NA Sectionname_AB
#> 7  activity_f NA NA  3 Sectionname_AB
#> 8  activity_g  3 NA NA Sectionname_AB
#> 9  activity_h  3 NA NA Sectionname_AB
#> 10 activity_i NA NA NA Sectionname_AB
#> 12 activity_j  2 NA NA Sectionname_BC
#> 13 activity_k  1 NA NA Sectionname_BC
#> 14 activity_l  1  3 NA Sectionname_BC
#> 15 activity_m  3 NA  2 Sectionname_BC
#> 16 activity_n  3 NA  2 Sectionname_BC
#> 17 activity_o  2 NA NA Sectionname_BC
```